# Windows unable to resolve hostnames

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dns

I have two Windows 7 machines on my home network that always give 'Unreachable' errors when I try to access any site. The other devices on the same network work fine (iPhone, iPad, Mac, Ubuntu)
The problem started when the router was reset but this problem doesn't seem to be caused by the router.

I have already tried changing the authentication settings, used open DNS servers but to no effect. Websites are reachable via IP addresses but not hostnames.
Also, most of the times it starts working automatically.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is how to resolve it.

Thanks

Edit: I guess my question now is - how do I troubleshoot DNS. I can ping the DNS servers but cannot do an nslookup

Comment: It's pretty dumb but check `services.msc` (or Services console) and see if your DNS resolver/client is running

Comment: Are you using DHCP configuration on your Win7?

Comment: Tried with both DNS client started and stopped, same issue. The description says DNS client is just a cache, so it shouldn't matter even if it's not running.

Yes, I am using DHCP config, IPv4 is set to get IPs automatically from router, I've just modified the DNS to open DNS IPs

Comment: Is the IPv6 box checked under the NIC properties.  If it is, and you aren't using v6 try unchecking and try it again.  Also, just out of curiosity, do you get the same results when you run IE with no addons?

Comment: Yes, I have tried disabling IPv6.
The browser doesn't matter, I cannot look up any domain using any application including the command line.

Comment: If you do an `ipconfig /all` on the devices where DNS lookups are working and also on the two Win 7 systems where DNS lookups aren't working, do you see the same IP addresses for the DNS servers on all of the systems? I mention that because I've seen situations where there are multiple systems on a LAN acting as DHCP servers, e.g., a Windows server and a router or two routers, so the settings a DHCP client gets will depend on which DHCP server answers the DHCP client query first. Also verify that you don't have firewall software on the systems limiting outbound access to port 53, the DNS port.

Comment: Try manually setting your DNS in the IPv4 settings, just use 8.8.8.8 for primary 8.8.8.9 for secondary, they're googles.

Comment: I've had this issue but I also couldn't change DNS settings. Uninstalled and reinstalled the network driver and all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. open up the command prompt
2. try the command: ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: This is the most likely fix, since the OP is able to ping machines by IP address.  A complete reboot is likely to fix it, as is uninstalling / reinstalling the network drivers (but make sure you have the installer first).