# NSLookup Unable To Resolve Local Computer's Hostname

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, nslookup

I went through all of the suggestions here:
[Windows unable to resolve hostnames](https://superuser.com/questions/636660/windows-unable-to-resolve-hostnames)

I recently discovered that I cannot resolve any Windows host name (i.e., the computer name). For example, if open a command prompt (all machines run Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit) and enter NSLOOKUP TEMP, I receive the message: `*** router.asus.com can't find TEMP: None-existent domain`.

I can PING -a 192.168.3.101 (the static-IP of my desktop computer), and that's not only successful but also reports the correct host name TEMP while doing so.

What could be the broken link here that's preventing NSLookup from being able to resolve the name TEMP?

P.S. My ethernet adapter's properties point to my router's gateway as the primary DNS: 192.168.3.1. I can do an NSLookup on external internet sites successfully, such as msn.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like in the thread before your router most likely isn't your DNS server its just proxy which forward your requests to real DNS server somewhere else. So if DNS server outside would try to resolve your pc hostname to ip address it's just impossible because:

- hostnames are not unique in global scale unlike website names with
  top-level domain like .org so there could be 100 000 PCs with TEMP name with 100 000 different IP addresses

If you really want that your setup will work with resolving local hostnames you need to create your own DNS server for example as a service on Windows Server then if you will point your DNS queries to this local DNS server then it should work.

Comment: Hmmmm. Sure, that makes sense. But maybe I am trying to solve a problem the wrong way. The real issue is that I cannot resolve computer names on my network using UNC. I used to be able to browse \\TEMP and see its shares. Now  I can't. If this is unrelated to NSLookup (as it seems to be) then I will post another question (!) and accept your answer. (By the way, I can browse another computer's resources using that computer's IP address-just not its name; and the UNC paths were working until recently and I have Windows Update turned off--but I can't figure out what changed!).

Comment: Did you checked: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center ? Maybe your network is marked as public so you can try to set is as private or change sharing options here: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

Comment: Yes, it's private. Both computers are private. Let's continue on another thread. I will accept your answer here and post the new thread in a moment.

Comment: New question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1461065/lost-ability-to-resolve-unc-path-on-windows-10-host-to-vmware-guest